# Asp.net mvc5 two matching strings return false?

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, asp.net-mvc-5.2

Working on a project where I compare two string, how ever the string do match but it returns false for some reason...

**This is the code I try to run to compare:**

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Projects", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    {
        var allProjects = ViewData["allProjects"] as List<Project>;
        <h3>
            <a href="#">Inhouse projekt</a>
        </h3>
        <div>
            @{
                Html.RenderPartial("Projects", allProjects.Where(x => x.ProjectStatu.Name == "Pågående - Inhouse"));
            }
        </div>
        <h3>
            <a href="#">Outhouse projekt</a>
        </h3>
        <div>
            @{
                Html.RenderPartial("Projects", allProjects.Where(x => x.ProjectStatu.Name == "Pågående - Outhouse"));
            }
        </div>
        <h3>
            <a href="#">Övriga projekt</a>
        </h3>
        <div>
            @{
                Html.RenderPartial("Projects", allProjects.Where(x => x.ProjectStatu.Name != "Pågående - Inhouse" && x.ProjectStatu.Name != "Pågående - Outhouse" && x.ProjectStatu.Name != "Avslutat"));
            }
        </div>
        <h3>
            <a href="#">Avslutade projekt</a>
        </h3>
        <div>
            @{
                Html.RenderPartial("Projects", allProjects.Where(x => x.ProjectStatu.Name == "Avslutat"));
            }
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="Spara" id="submit" name="submit" style="padding: 5px 20px 5px 20px; float: right;" />
     }
 }
```

Proof the two string's do match but it returns a false..
[image]

Comment: I dont know if it is due to font in code window vs locals window. Is it "I" in Inhouse causing the difference?

Comment: It's due the font in the code windows vs the local window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of doing your comparison like that, instead you should use [string.Compare](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hyxc48dt(v=vs.110).aspx). The link there also includes the Culture Info, which will probably be relevant in your case.

```
allProjects.Where(x => string.Compare(x.ProjectStatu.Name, {your string}, false, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

I say this because I could easily see there being a problem with the Unicode formats of the two strings. This should get around that.

Comment: I am going to assume it's due problem with the Unicode format since on some views I can't use ÅÄÖ but on some others I can...

Answer (score 0):

Try using `allProjects.Where(x => x.ProjectStatu.Name.Contains("Inhouse"))`